# Action Ok & Cancel button in DatePicker MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to add action buttons such as "Ok" & "Cancel" underneath the calendar in Desktop view. How do I implement action buttons with [MUI DateRangePicker](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-range-picker/) ?.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `componentsProps`:

```
componentsProps={{
    actionBar: {
        // The actions will be the same between desktop and mobile
        actions: ["cancel", "accept"]
    }
}}
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicdaterangepicker-demo-mui-x-forked-wbpjge?file=/demo.tsx)

[Documentation](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/custom-components/)

Comment: Note: `componentsProps` is now deprecated. Use `slotProps` instead.